# Swift - how to split an amount of money equally between a group of people?

Tags: swift, dictionary, for-loop, optimization

I'm building a clone banking app at the moment, and one of the things I'm trying to do is add 'Split Transaction' (which can then be shared with a set of friends paying a given amount each).

Initially, the transaction is split equally amongst friends (unless it doesn't split equally, in which case the remainder gets added on to one unlucky friend). The user can then manually adjust the amount each pays, which then updates the others. If the user has manually adjust an amount for a friend, this friends 'split' doesn't get updated automatically if the user then adjust another friend's amount (i.e. if the user says friend1 pays £12, it will always be £12 until the user says otherwise).

I've been fiddling for a while trying to make the method as concise and 'swifty' as possible - but I'd really appreciate any feedback on my approach.

For the purposes here, I'm only trying split the money equally between people (but I still wanted to explain the 'user defined split' so the current code makes sense).

I'm using https://github.com/Flight-School/Money to represent the transaction value, all within a Transaction class. I need to round quite a bit to ensure the split and remainder stick to 2 decimal places. Here's the relevant code:

A struct to hold an amount along with if the user set it or not (needs to be custom object for codable reasons):

```
struct SplitTransactionAmount: Codable {
    let amount: Money<GBP>
    let setByUser: Bool
}
```

A dictionary to hold the friend names, along with their split, and if it's set by the user - also a namesOfPeopleSplittingTransaction array for easy display.

```
var splitTransaction: [String: SplitTransactionAmount]
var namesOfPeopleSplittingTransaction = [String]()
```

And here's the method to split the transaction:

```
private func splitTransaction(amount: Money<GBP>, with friends: [String]) -> [String: SplitTransactionAmount] {

    //First we remove any duplicate names.
    let uniqueFriends = friends.removingDuplicates()
    //Create an empty dictionary to hold the new values before returning.
    var newSplitTransaction = [String: SplitTransactionAmount]()

    let totalAmountToSplitRounded = amount.rounded.amount
    let numberOfSplitters = uniqueFriends.count

    let eachTotalRaw = totalAmountToSplitRounded / Decimal(numberOfSplitters)
    let eachTotalRounded = Money<GBP>(eachTotalRaw).rounded.amount

    let remainder = totalAmountToSplitRounded - (Decimal(numberOfSplitters) * eachTotalRounded)

    if remainder == 0 {
        //If the amount to split each goes in to the total with no remainder, everyone pays the same.
        for friend in uniqueFriends {
            newSplitTransaction[friend] = SplitTransactionAmount(amount: Money(eachTotalRounded), setByUser: false)
        }
    } else {
        for friend in uniqueFriends {
            if friend == uniqueFriends.first! {
                //Unlucky first friend has to pay a few pence more!
                newSplitTransaction[friend] = SplitTransactionAmount(amount: Money(eachTotalRounded + remainder), setByUser: false)
            } else {
                newSplitTransaction[friend] = SplitTransactionAmount(amount: Money(eachTotalRounded), setByUser: false)
            }
        }
    }
    return newSplitTransaction
}
```

I think the problem I'm finding is the code makes perfect sense to me, but I'm not sure how clear it is to an outside reader. Any thoughts on my approach would be much appreciated (and sorry for the long question!). And I'd also love to know if there's anyway to write this more concisely!

Many thanks

Comment: I think this belongs at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since I don’t really see a question about some issue being asked here.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I didn't know CodeReview existed! Will move this to there!

Answer (score 0):

IMO, Simplify into a single loop over two loops on different `ifs` . And reduce repeated code (e.g init of SplitTransactionAmount)

```
 for (index, friend) in uniqueFriends.enumerated(){ //or if you don't prefer enumerated, use == on first index like before.
    let money: Money<GBP>
    if remainder != 0, index == 0 { //ensure remainder is only used if has value.
        //Unlucky first friend has to pay a few pence more!
        money = Money(eachTotalRounded + remainder)
   } else {
        money = Money(eachTotalRounded)
   }


    newSplitTransaction[friend] = SplitTransactionAmount(amount: money setByUser: false)

 }
```